# player dies when he touches the floor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a game following a YouTube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPV2KyIb3jR5QFsefuO2RlAgWEz6EvVi6 I am on episode 8 and when I start the game the end game text comes up and I assume it is because the player touches the ground I cannot see any difference between the coding that I have produced and the YouTuber

GAME MANAGER:
    using UnityEngine;

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
bool gameHasEnded = false;
// Start is called before the first frame update
public void EndGame ()
{
    if (gameHasEnded == false)
    {
        gameHasEnded = true;
        Debug.Log("GAME OVER");

    }


}
}
```

PLAYER COLLISIONS:
    using UnityEngine;

```
public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{

public PlayerMovement movement;

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Block")
    {
        movement.enabled = false;
    }   FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
}
}
```

PLAYER MOVEMENT:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{   //to substitute rigidbody to rb
public Rigidbody rb;

public float forwardForce = 2000f;

public float sidewaysForce = 500f;

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    //add forward force
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
    //only exectued if condition is met
    if ( Input.GetKey("d") )
    {
        rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, 
ForceMode.VelocityChange);


    }

    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, 
ForceMode.VelocityChange);


    }
    if (rb.position.y < -1f)
    {
       FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Double check the starting Y position of your player GameObject, I'm guessing it's positioned below -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Block")
    {
        movement.enabled = false;
    }   FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();// <--- It is outside the if
}
```

Should be like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Block")
    {
        movement.enabled = false;
        FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
    }
}
```

It ended the game whenever you collided with something, instead of doing it when it is a block only.